# Generate jar file with libraries WITHOUT runnable jar file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, file, jar, libraries

I can't find the option to generate a jar file with all the java source files,resources and the libraries in the project. There is a way doing it with a runnable jar file but this is NOT what I am looking for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you could install an eclipse plugin: fatjar, it can help you create an all-in-one jar.
2. If you use maven to buid, you can use a plug-in: shade or assembly

Comment: Not the best way cause it's alpha and it is not working for luna version. But I have just installed kepler and it works, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with Ant.  Requires no plugins and will work in Luna.

build.xml:

```
<project name="makejar" default="jar">
    <property name="src.dir"        location="src"/>
    <property name="build.dir"      location="build"/>
    <property name="lib.dir"        location="lib"/>   
    <property name="resources.dir"  location="resources"/>

    <target name="jar">
        <jar destfile="${build.dir}/MyJar.jar" basedir="${src.dir}">
            <fileset id="resources" dir="${resources.dir}" />
            <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
        </jar>          
    </target>
</project>
```

Right-click and select "Run as Ant Build".

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 2:

For a simple jar file :

**File -> export -> java -> Jar file -> Next -> (select what ever you want to include ) -> choose "library handeling" -> finish**

For an excecutable jar file:

**File -> export -> java -> Runnable jar file -> choose your main package -> name your file -> choose "library handeling" -> finish**

Comment: There is only the option to export the src and the settings folder. I just downloaded this Version [link](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Kepler/SR2)

Comment: @user3160135 that is the version I have, it should work for you.

Comment: Just to be sure... can you upload a screen dump of the option? I can't see this option to export a jar file with the libraries.

Comment: u mean this: [https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/104212866/runnable.png](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/104212866/runnable.png)

Comment: No I wanted to export a normal jar file (NOT runnable jar file) with the libraries. The library handling is not showing up in exporting jar file.

Comment: @user3160135 the options are the same, just follow the first instruction( instead of using **runnable jar file**, choose **Jar file**

Comment: @user3160135 my apologies, it seems I made a mistake. normal jar file doesn't have this option.

Comment: @user3160135 I'll delete my post in few minutes